# How to count pattern occurrence in a file using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

I have two files. A large one with plain data and one which has patterns separated in lines.

How to count all pattern occurrences in large file using map reduce algorithm, specially in `Apache Spark` engine using python (pyspark).

DataFile:

```
ABCDEFABCDERFADACCABCDEABA.....
```

PattenFile:

```
ABC
BCF
CDE
```

Comment: I'm new to Spark, i have just read examples. PattenFile have 100 records at most,

Comment: What about the `DataFile`? is it already split?

Comment: No, it's a one big file(1GB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `PattenFile` is small (meaning fits on your master, supposing you are using a cluster), I will just tell you the gist of what you need, I hope you finish it. Notice that I will suppose that you already split the data in `DataFile` in trios.

1. Load both files.

   ```py
   data = sc.textFile("DataFile")
   pattern = sc.textFile("PatternFile")
   ```
2. Broadcast the dictionary (`patternFile`), as you said It's small enough.

   ```py
   dictionary = pattern.collect()
   broadcast_dictionary = sc.broadcast(dictionary)
   ```
3. Filter your `data`.

   ```py
   data = data.filter(lambda x: x in dictionary.value)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the solution of @Alberto Bonsanto, here is how you can split your data into trios. Unfortunately pyspark does not seem to offer a `sliding` method. Coding this by hand is fairly cumbersome.

```
dat0=flatMap(lambda x:list(x))
        .zipWithIndex()
        .filter(lambda (_,i): i>=0)
        .groupBy(lambda (_,i): i/3).values()
        .map(lambda x: 
          reduce(lambda y1,y2: 
            y1+''+y2,map(lambda (u,_):u,list(x))
           )
         )
```

Moreover, you will also need to create analogs `dat1` and `dat2`, where `filter(lambda (_,i): i>=0)` is replaced by `filter(lambda (_,i): i>=1)` and `filter(lambda (_,i): i>=2)` in order to take possible offsets into account.